# How to filter documents using 'fq' in Solr based on two or more fields?

Tags: python, filter, solr, lucene

Let us say I have a Solr6.5 core containing metadata for each entry and I want to eliminate a few entries during specific queries based on the values of the fields.

For example, for every entry (document) I have many fields, let's consider two, field1 and field2.

How do I remove only entries that have both field1 = 'x' and field2 = 'a' (The Intersection)

Im querying Solr from Python as a get request.

I have tried sending the 'fq' parameter in the request as a string, where,

```
    'fq' : '-field1:x AND -field2:a'
```

Also, this part of the fq is a part of a larger fq on several other fields. But for those fields, I do not worry about any intersections

It is reducing the number of found entries for queries significantly. I suspect that the entries with field1=x and field2:a are getting eliminated independently but I want the elimination to occur only when both the conditions are met.

Am I handling this correctly or is there a better/correct way of ensuring only the intersection is eliminated?

Is adding parenthesis around that part of the larger fq make it work?

e.g:

```
    'fq' : '....other-conditions..... AND (-field1:x AND -field2:a) AND ....other-conditions.....'
```

Will this help? Am I using the AND condition improperly?

Here  https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html  I found that an & is used, but I assume that that is used as a curl command.

Comment: `*:* -(field1:x AND field2:a)`? That way you start with all documents and remove the set containing the documents matching both terms.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for the help! Can I use this simultaneously with the other conditions in the 'fq' string?  like  'fq' : '....other-conditions..... AND *:* -(field1:x AND field2:a) AND ....other-conditions.....'

Comment: Yes, that should work fine. `AND` find the intersection of the sets on both sides. You might want to throw `()` around it to make it work properly.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Will replace `(-field1:x AND -field2:a)` in my initial code with `*:* -(field1:x AND field2:a)` and check. Thanks again!

Comment: Did it work as expected?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes it did. Thank you!